# What is the equivalent of XML configuration inheritance into Java based configs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-context

I understand Spring has configuration based inheritance, that means I can create beans referencing another bean as parent and Spring will copy the properties defined to the child. I'm looking on how to do the same with Java-based Spring configurations. I'll illustrate with the following example:

In Spring configurations I can define the following `Properties` class for holding values:

```
package com.example

class Properties {
    String valueA;
    String valueB;
    String valueC;
}
```

Later on a Spring XML configuration I can define the following 3 beans with configuration inheritance:

```
<bean id="propertiesBase" class="com.example.Properties">
    <property name="valueA" value="someValueForA"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertiesChild" parent="propertiesBases">
    <property name="valueB" value="someValueForB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertiesGrandChild" parent="propertiesChild">
    <property name="valueC" value="someValueForC"/>
</bean>
```

This results in `propertiesBase` with `someValueForA`, propertiesChild having `someValueForA` and `someValueForB`, finally propertiesGrandChild having `someValueForA`, `someValueForB` and `someValueForC`

I figure in Spring Java based configurations I can define something similar as this

```
package com.example.config

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.example.Properties;

@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "propertiesBase")
    Properties getPropertiesBase() {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setValueA("someValueForA");
        return p;
    }

    @Bean(name = "propertiesChild")
    Properties getPropertiesChild(@Qualifier("propertiesBase") Properties parent) {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setValueA(parent.getValueA());
        p.setValueB("someValueForB");
        return p;
    }

    @Bean(name = "propertiesGrandChild")
    Properties getPropertiesGrandChild(@Qualifier("propertiesChild") Properties parent) {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setValueA(parent.getValueA());
        p.setValueB(parent.getValueB());
        p.setValueC("someValueForC");
        return p;
    }
}
```

But this approach has the problem that, if the class `Properties` changes, then all `Bean` definitions needs to change accordingly to keep the values propagating. Is there another approach for this problem, that does not suffer from the latter problem?

Comment: Does the XML approach not suffer from that problem? What behaviour would you expect instead?

Comment: I guess I was not specific enough, I mean with change on class Properties, what if a new field valueD is introduced and bean `propertiesBase` has the property set, then on the Java based approach I need to change each method to propagate the valueD, but on the XML approach I do not need to do such propagation.

Comment: It's Java code, you can do literally anything you want. Just extract a method that does the default configuration on the parent and call it for the children. This way, if the parent configuration changes, all you'll need to do will be to update that method